# Open source BI tool for reporting

Tags: open-source, data-visualization, data-analysis

Can some one please suggest an opensource BI reporting interface which is best for gaming industry.

Requirement is to analyze the basic KPI's new users ,unique users,Life time value retention and also the in game stats.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/ suits your needs ?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/best-free-alternative-to-tableau