# What open source program will graph data from mysql database?

Tags: linux, open-source, graphs, mysql, reporting

I am looking for an open-source program to accomplish the same things that can be done with Qlik or PowerBI.  The main difference is that I want the processing to be done on the server side rather than to be self contained in a file and processed in memory.  Any suggestions? Dynamic reports rather than static reports are preferred, as I am already using Reportserver for my reports. This tool I wish to use for data exploration.

Comment: Will you be doing any coding yourself?

Comment: I located a program that would accomplish my goal. I am using Metabase.

Comment: You can post that as an answer, to help others in future. It would also help to post a URL.

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), a [python](http://www.python.org/) library, is:

- Free & Open Source *as is python.*
- BSD Licence, *python is PSF*, both allow commercial use
- Is cross platform, *(for just about every platform up to super computers)*.
- Can be run **both** server side or client side
- Can interface with mySQL, *(and the majority of other databases)*.
- Has a number of [visualisations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) and can interface to more

The good news is that as it can run both client & server side you can develop client side and then simply upload to the server.

Comment: This looks interesting however from what I have been able to research it looks as though it is a back-end rather than an all-inclusive solution. Am I overlooking something? I do not have much coding experience other than sequel so something with a user interface would be a better solution for my situation.

Comment: @AaronMartin for a user interface you can use pandas within a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau Desktop will read from certain databases and plot the data. It does many other things as well. Its totally point and click but learning curve not steep, but not simple either. There is a free version at Tableau public. You have to store your files on their server though. So if this is proprietary or personal you're best to avoid it. A single user license is not cheap. This tool is specifically used for data exploration and was introduced to me through a data science online tutorial.

Comment: See also [Best Free Alternative to Tableau](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/best-free-alternative-to-tableau)