# BI engine with REST API to retrieve data

Tags: rest

I will explain my use case. We are developing a web application to show an analytics dashboard for our customers. The information shown has to do with KPIs and metrics extracted through an ETL process from their databases.

Due to an architectural decision we want our web application to access the backend only through web services, so there is a clear separation between front-end and back-end. Thus we need a REST API that returns the desired data when we send a request.

For example, suppose our fact table is about employee salaries and we want to show a graph with the average employee salaries year on year aggregated by employee category. We would send a request like GET to `http://api.example.com/salaries?group-by=year&group-by=employee-category&operation=average`. It should return the requested data in XML or JSON format, something like the example below.

We have thought about using Qlik or Power BI, but it seems their APIs are Javascript APIs that must be executed on the client side, and the only REST APIs they have are for management.

Do you know a BI software engine **that offers this kind of REST API** out of the box?

Example response:

```
    [
       {
          "year":2012,
          "salaries":[
             {
                "category":"rookie",
                "salary":30000
             },
             {
                "category":"senior",
                "salary":45000
             }
          ]
       }, 
       {
          "year":2013,
          "salaries":[
             {
                "category":"rookie",
                "salary":35000
             },
             {
                "category":"senior",
                "salary":47000
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Would that be usefull? https://github.com/metabase/metabase/wiki/Using-the-REST-API

Comment: What are you storing your data in? With `mongodb` there are http interfaces, and both python and java REST API generators for it.  For MySQL or MariaDB there are quite a few available there as well.

Comment: @ivanivan `mongodb` and `MySQL` are database backends, the question is about BI engines. Of course, the BI engine will access some kind of database backend, but the question is about a REST API attached to the BI engine, not the database.

Comment: I don’t mean to nit-pick, but I think your example has problems, so let’s hope that it is only an example. 1group-by=year&group-by=employee-category` has two `group-by`. What would, for instance, PHP return for `$_GET[‘group-by’]`? And you would you know if both year & employee category had been selected? I suggest either `group-by=year|employee-category` or `group-by-time=year& group-by-category=True`, or some such.

Answer (score 0):

[Logi Analytics](https://www.logianalytics.com) provides a rest API for data. It can also render a full fledged visualization that way, but you can get the data and put your own visualization in front of it as well.

Specifically you are looking for their Discovery module and it's DataView concept

Comment: Do you know how much it costs? I couldn't see pricing.

Comment: @Mawg, as with all vendors in this space, it is a lot. They have different mixes of products as well. You will have to talk to sales.

Comment: Sounds like time for a new question :-) Is there a gratis alternative?

Comment: @Mawg, not of Logi Analytics, no. An open source BI tool that meets the criteria of the question? Never heard of one.

Comment: I know little or nothing of the topic, but would a [free alternative to Tableau](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/best-free-alternative-to-tableau) be of any use?

Comment: @Mawg, that wouldn't have the REST API, necessarily. I didn't investigate much of that question, but the Qlik free version would not.