# Open-source alternative to Tableau 'Ask Data' Feature

Tags: open-source, data-visualization

Looking for free software or r/python coding packages for embedding on a public health data website that lets data-illiterate users build their own visualizations from a pre-determined set of variables, preferably using easy natural language processing inputs as in Tableau '[Ask Data](https://10az.online.tableau.com/#/site/demodepot/datasources/11834148/askData)' but drag-and-drop at minimum.

Needs to make dataviz easy for non-data folks given a set of variables to work with. As opposed to me building custom vizes or dashboards for people. Looks like Tableau won't let me use Ask Data through their free Tableau Public channel.

Comment: MIght https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/best-free-alternative-to-tableau be of help?

Comment: Thanks @Mawg -- looking for a specific feature, not just a general alternative to Tableau. If the solution is in R I'm curious what package to look in. I suspect since the Tableau 'Ask Data' feature is new and based on natural language+AI that it won't be easy for me to find an alternative. It's so neat how Ask Data guesses what type of viz to create for you based on text you enter

Comment: Yes, I saw that about the feature, but thought that maybe one of the alternatives mentioned could help. Not if it's a new feature, though :-(  Good luck

Comment: Your link to 'Ask Data' leads to a log in page. Is there some description of the feature that is openly accessible?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't an alternative to Ask Data but actually potentially using Ask Data. The Tableau Foundation offers grants for free licenses for Tableau Online/Desktop/etc. so that might be an avenue to explore. (full disclosure - my employer PATH is a Tableau Foundation grantee).